# QListView in gridmode: auto stretch with fixed items on a row / column

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to make a simple grid with `QListView`, e.g 3x3, but the `gridSize()` option in `QListView` doesn't work that way, it's the width/height of all child widgets in `QListView`, how should I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.resize(600,400)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.list.addItems(['item_%d' % i for i in xrange(9)])
        self.list.setViewMode(self.list.IconMode)
        self.list.setResizeMode(self.list.Adjust)
        self.list.installEventFilter(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.list and event.type() == event.Resize:
            gridsize = self.list.size()/3
            # remove from width to account for the scrollbar
            gridsize.setWidth(gridsize.width()-15)
            self.list.setGridSize(gridsize)

        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

While I had thought the gridSize was the entire list, its actually per cell. The key things here are to set the resize mode to adjust, so that its always re-evaluating the item sizes, and also to keep adjusting the gridSize every time the list widget resizes. In my example, I am using an event filter, but you could also subclass the list and re-implement the resizeEvent.

The size of the list is divided by 3 and then some padding is removed for the scrollbars. The result is that the items are laid out in 3x width and keep resizing with the view.

Comment: Yeah, actually I want the item size to be auto-resizable, whiling keeping the e.g 3x3 grid layout, is that possible without implementing e.g resizeEvent()

Comment: Try setting lisview.setResizeMode to Adjust

Comment: @warl0ck: There you go. That should do it I think